# MySQL: group by column in specific order (not just ASC or DESC)

Tags: mysql, sorting, unique

I have a query that is working... however I want to be able to sort/order in a particular way.
My current query (for example) returns date like this:

```
CenterID, OrgName, ID, Relationship, REL_START_YEAR, REL_END_YEAR, Full_Name

(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Fellow', '1971', '1971', 'Robert B. Winter, MD'),
(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Founder', '1971', '1972', 'Robert C. Summer, MD'),
(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Faculty', '1971', '1974', 'Robert D. Spring, MD'),
(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Fellow', '1972', '1974', 'Robert A. Fall, MD'),
(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Faculty', '1975', '1976', 'Ginger B. Jones, MD'),
(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Founder', '1977', '1978', 'Mary F. Johnson, MD'),
(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Faculty', '1971', '1972', 'Shawn S. Dimmer, MD'),
(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Fellow', '1978', '1978', 'Scotty B. Raw, MD'),
(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Fellow', '1978', '1981', 'Lou V. Louis, MD'),
(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Founder', '1984', '1984', 'Paula L. Davis, MD'),
(84864, 'Twin Cities Spine Center', '19100', 'Fellow', '1981', '1982', 'Nadine H. Ericson, MD');
```

However I'd like to sort/order/group things

FIRST by the Relationship column.. but not just in an alpha sort.. I want it to be listed as

Founders first
Faculty second
Fellow third...

and then each 'group' above being sorted by the REL_START_YEAR

This gets me close.. but not the granular control over the order of the Relationship column:

```
SELECT o.CenterID
     , o.OrgName
     , r.ID
     , r.Relationship
     , r.REL_START_YEAR
     , r.REL_END_YEAR
     , u.ID
     , u.Full_Name 
  FROM genealogy_orgs o
  JOIN genealogy_relations r
    ON r.CenterID = o.CenterID 
  JOIN genealogy_users u
    ON u.ID = r.ID 
 WHERE o.CenterID = 84864
 ORDER 
    BY r.Relationship DESC
     , r.REL_START_YEAR ASC;
```

What am I looking for in order to be able to sort/group by a unique order in the Relationship column?  Some sort of use of the IN() function?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is "MS MySQL" (in your title)? Are you using Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Or just see FIELD()

Comment: Sorry. I removed MS form the title (brain fart)

@Strawberry
Perfect! thats exactly what I needed/was looking for.  Make it an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: Also... I tried to make an 'example'... but got errors.. Its not the easiest app to work with.

Example:
http://rextester.com/GTI4488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(relationship VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,year INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (relationship,year)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('Fellow' ,1971),
('Founder',1971),
('Faculty',1971),
('Fellow' ,1972),
('Faculty',1975),
('Founder',1977),
('Faculty',1974),
('Fellow' ,1978),
('Founder',1984),
('Fellow' ,1981); 

SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 ORDER 
    BY FIELD(relationship,'Founder','Faculty','Fellow')
     , year;
+--------------+------+
| relationship | year |
+--------------+------+
| Founder      | 1971 |
| Founder      | 1977 |
| Founder      | 1984 |
| Faculty      | 1971 |
| Faculty      | 1974 |
| Faculty      | 1975 |
| Fellow       | 1971 |
| Fellow       | 1972 |
| Fellow       | 1978 |
| Fellow       | 1981 |
+--------------+------+
```

But note that you can handle this sort of thing just as well in application code (php/javascript, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> Founders first Faculty second Fellow third..

```
ORDER BY CASE Relationship 
  WHEN 'Founders' THEN 1 WHEN 'Faculty' THEN 2 WHEN 'Fellow' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END, 
  REL_START_YEAR -- Not entirely sure what your requirements are here..
```